# How to give double quotes to column with strings that have comma's in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that has a column of strings that has comma's inside the string. If i want to read the csv using pandas it sees the extra comma's as extra columns.Which gives me the error of have more rows then expected. I thought of using double quotes around the strings as solution to the problem.

This is how the csv currently looks

```
   lead,Chat.Event,Role,Data,chatid
   lead,x,Lead,Hello, how are you,1
```

How it should look like

```
   lead,Chat.Event,Role,Data,chatid
   lead,x,Lead,"Hello, how are you",1
```

Is using double quotes around the strings the best solution? and if yes how do i do that? And if not what other solution can you recommend?

Comment: Let the `csv` package handle such details: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html.

Comment: Yes, double quotes works fine. But are you asking how to inject double quotes into a CSV that already has strings with commas in them?

Comment: yes pshep123, or is there an other way to connect the full string to the column? instead of having just Hello being attached to the Data column.

Comment: Could say something like: after the third comma the string starts, and the string can be closed before the last comma.

Comment: You could then pre-process the file to replace all valid commas with ; and use that as a separator for reading the csv.

Answer (score 0):

if you got the original file / database through which you generated the csv, you should do it again using a different kind of separator (the default is comma), one which you would not have within your strings, such as "|" (vertical bar).

than, when reading the csv with pandas, you can just pass the argument:

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="your separator symbol here")
```

hope that helps